# Sequelize findAll() without where clause returns less rows than a SELECT COUNT in database

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

When using Sequelize and a findAll on a table I get 2994 rows but I know that there are 11909 rows in this table using a SELECT COUNT(*) directly into the database. Below is the example of the code:

```js
// using "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM collection;" into database returns 11909
​
const test: number[] = (await Collection.findAll({
    attributes: ['id']
})).map((collection: Collection) => collection.id);
​
console.log(test.length); // 2994
```

I have already verified my Sequelize model and everything is fine, I just don't understand why Sequelize.findAll() does not return all rows.
Thank you for your help if any of you has already encountered this issue.

Comment: Anyway I figured out, when deleting my instances using sequelize I did not used parameter { force: true } and as sequelize is set as paranoid it just update the "deleted_at" column in the database but does not delete the row. That's why I had still the same amount of rows with "SELECT COUNT(*)" but a different amount returned by sequelize

Answer (score 0):

After dropping the table and importing the data Sequelize.findAll() returns the right amount of rows. I don't know what the problem was but everything is good now.